# Alchemist and Healer's Touch interaction

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, magic

How does the feat [Healer's Touch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/achievement-feats/healer-s-touch-achievement/) interact with an alchemist?

From my initial reading, since alchemist extracts are considered 'spells' it would work, so long as it was used on others via infusion.

Assuming that was the case, I was then looking at the [Healing Bomb](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/healing-bomb/) discovery. This would be used on others, and if the former assumption is correct, then how would this work with Healer's touch? Since the minimum amount of damage the heal spell is capable of healing, is actually the maximum since it is maximized.

Would a CLW bomb, heal 8+5 to everyone including the target? Or is the former assumption wrong entirely, negating the need for the latter question to be answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No. Alchemists don't cast spells.

[Healer's Touch](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Healer%27s%20Touch) states:

> When you **cast a healing spell** to heal a target other than yourself, the spell is maximized as though using the Maximize Spell effect. This does not increase your casting time for the spell. When you cast a healing spell to damage a target, the spell is not maximized but its saving throw DC increases by +4.

[Alchemist](https://www.aonprd.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Alchemist) states:

> **Although the alchemist doesn’t actually cast spells**, he does have a formulae list that determines what extracts he can create.

There's also the [FAQ (about crafting)](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9qdk), that states:

> As written, no, **alchemists are not spellcasters**, and therefore can't select feats such as Craft Wondrous Item.

Additionally, while a GM may houserule that an alchemist's extracts count as spells (a somewhat *'eh, sure'* houserule), ***bombs are a completely separate thing***. So even if their extracts count as spells, bombs do not, and therefore would not be affected by Healer's touch.